Getting series cardinality from the influxdb-client-java
I'm currently working on benchmarking timeseries databases with java, and i have an issue with influxdb.
I'm trying to get the series cardinality from database "myDb" using the following command :
SHOW SERIES CARDINALITY ON myDb

through this code :
String query = "SHOW SERIES CARDINALITY ON "+database; \\ database correspond to "myDb"
InfluxQLQueryResult results = qlQueryApi.query(new InfluxQLQuery(query,database));
LOGGER.info("{}", results.getResults().get(0).getSeries().get(0).getValues().get(0).getValues());

And i got an empty result (results.getResults().get(0).getSeries() is an empty list)
I tried this, with ZYWHNYFLGLN being a measurement
String query = "SHOW SERIES CARDINALITY FROM \"ZYWHNYFLGLN\"";
and it works, moreover when i try my "SHOW SERIES CARDINALITY ON myDb" on influx shell it works perfectly fine.
I'm using influxdb 1.8.10, influxdb-client-java 6.9.0
I tried showing series cardinality from a measurment which is working , and i tried the same query on the influx shell and it's also working
